# How do I insert a triple into GraphDB from an Apache Nifi flow

Tags: sparql, apache-nifi, graphdb

I'm in the process of learning Ontotext GraphDB and Apache Nifi. I'm coming from a relational background and tools like SSIS. I would like to read a json file in Nifi and then insert a triple derived from that json into my GraphDB. I haven't been able to find much content to guide me. How do you insert to GraphDB from Nifi?

I'm using the Pizza Ontology in GraphDB and my json test file just defines a new NamedPizza to add.

I can read the json in Nifi, but I'm not sure how to perform the insert to GraphDB from Nifi. I expected there to be an RDF writer processor in Nifi according to my research, but it doesn't show as an available processor in Nifi.

Comment: can't you use SPARQL update via HTTP then? I mean, either `LOAD <rdf_file_here>` or `INSERT DATA {:s :p :o`}`

Comment: What processor would one use in Nifi to do that?